# Non Updated Paint Graphics in Java

Tags: java

I want the tank to move in the screen but it doesn't update at all. If I am going to draw a ball...an oval...it does move in the screen, but since I want a picture to do so, I used the image method, but why does it stay on the window and does not even move even with the key listener method? Here is what I did:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{

Image tank;
 int x, y;
public class ActionListener extends KeyAdapter{


    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key == e.VK_LEFT) {
                x--;
            }
            if (key == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                x++;
            }
            if (key == e.VK_UP) {
                y--;
            }
            if (key == e.VK_DOWN) {
                y++;
            }
    }
    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
public Main () {
    x = 300;
    y = 320;
    addKeyListener(new ActionListener());

    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

}

public void paint (Graphics g) {

    Graphics gr = (Graphics2D) g;
    gr.drawImage(tank,0,0, null);
    tank = new ImageIcon (this.getClass().getResource("tank.png")).getImage();

    repaint ();
}

public static void main (String args []) {

    new Main ();
}
}
```

how can i fix this so it updates and moves the picture as I wanted it to? I even plan on making separate pictures for each direction, but with this problem I can't move on. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you first call drawImage, and then construct a new ImageIcon for the tank variable? That's weird

Answer (score -1):

This is the error

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics gr = (Graphics2D) g;
    gr.drawImage(tank,0,0, null);
    tank = new ImageIcon (this.getClass().getResource("tank.png")).getImage();
    repaint ();
}
```

Change it to

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics gr = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (tank==null){
        tank = new ImageIcon (this.getClass().getResource("tank.png")).getImage();
    }
    gr.drawImage(tank,0,0, null);
    repaint ();
}
```

Though calling `repaint` from `paint` could blow out your program.

Comment: People are here to get help, you might want to explain in details what is the error with their code.